# Modify connection pool properties after connection fails

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection-pooling

### The configuration

I have a pretty simple connection pool for my web app (programmed in Java 8, running on Tomcat 8). I retrieve the user, password and url for the connection from an external resource. This is how I initialize my data source:

```
    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
    p.setUrl(myURL); // Retrieved from external resource
    p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    p.setUsername(myUsrName); // Retrieved from external resource
    p.setPassword(myPassword); // Retrieved from external resource
    p.setJmxEnabled(true);
    p.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
    p.setMaxActive(300);
    p.setInitialSize(30);
    p.setMaxWait(30000);
    p.setMinIdle(10);
    p.setLogAbandoned(true);
    p.setJdbcInterceptors(
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer");
    DataSource newDataSource = new DataSource();
    newDataSource.setPoolProperties(p);
```

This configuration works perfectly for my needs, it can reconnect after connection problems with the DB arise.

### The problem

My current issue is that I am migrating my DB to a new server, so I know that the url connection string will change. How can I dynamically force the pool to be "rebuilt" with a new connection string without having to restart my application?

I want to be able to do something like this:

1. Web app is running connected to database A.
2. I migrate my database A to database B.
3. Change the external resource from where my web app gets the connection string so that it points to the new database B.
4. Remove access privileges from my app to database A.
5. App realizes it cannot establish a connection to database A, so it attempts to recreate the pool retrieving the new values from the external resource, which now contains the connection string to database B.
6. App connects to database B and continues to work normally.

### Considered options

I looked into interceptors to see if I could accomplish the desired behaviour by implementing my own interceptor, but it does not seem to be the right way to go.

Then I opted for the following: each time I catch a SQLException when trying to retrieve a connection from the pool, just recreate the entire datasource. While this may work, this solution seems... messy, to say the least.

### The Question

What would be the best way to get a connection pool that can attempt to change its connection string when it fails to connect to the DB that it had originally set in its properties?

Comment: You could simply update the `PoolProperties.url` when needed. It could be on a specific SQLException or using a event. This need to be checked of course (might find sometime this week-end to check)

Comment: I decided to go with the "rebuild on any exception" option. It worked fine.